# See only home screen and not my app when running the App

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm really freaking out of this problem, I've tried anything. Nothing works. When I run the app, android emulator just loads, shows the home screen and then nothing happens (I don't see my app running), just nothing. What should I do?

**EDIT:** Console code shows:

```
[2012-07-04 00:20:17 - MyAPPP] Android Launch!
[2012-07-04 00:20:17 - MyAPPP] adb is running normally.
[2012-07-04 00:20:17 - MyAPPP] Performing com.exame.myappp.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-07-04 00:20:17 - MyAPPP] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'MonoForAndroid_API_8'
[2012-07-04 00:20:17 - MyAPPP] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MonoForAndroid_API_8'
```

LogCat doesn't show anything

**EDIT2:** Manifest as requested :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.exame.myappp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Is this happening for this specific app or for all apps?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the emulator and unlocking it? You have to "use" the emulator otherwise, it will lock and not display your app. It will appear as if it isn't working, but all you have to do is "swipe" with your mouse and unlock it.

Comment: @BlaineAnderson Of course I did it.

Comment: You never know... Sometimes the simplest solution is the correct one.

Comment: @BlaineAnderson I'm really freaking out of that problem.. what do you suggest me to do? I'm trying to resolve it for more than 3 hours..

Comment: You don't have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>` in your manifest, is that just because you didn't include with your copy&paste?

Comment: Are you usinng mono for android? or just java?

Comment: @BlaineAnderson It's not there, I should add it? Where?

Comment: @Sean87 I'm using only JAVA, I used to use mono for android

Comment: YEah add that xml directive tags

Answer (score 1):

this could be an issue with Eclipse, sometimes when I run eclipse I have the same problem where the emulator runs, my app fails to run and when I try to run the app again I have a new emulator running.  What I usually find myself doing is build/clean the project, restart eclipse and then start again.

Sorry for the old techie "off/on" answer, hope it sorts itself out.

Answer (score 0):

Make your manifest look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.exame.myappp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Did you add the XML version info though?

Comment: Also make sure that you have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in all your XML layout files.

Comment: I think reinstalling emulator or even android sdk and stuff can help. Then for sake of testing, download a working app's source and see if it can run...